# What is the maximum number of pieces that a pizza can be cut into by 7 knife cuts? (NBHM 2005)

Tags: geometry, reference-request, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry

I am seeing this question very first time and do not know any formal way to solve it. Which part of mathematics it is related to?

**What is the maximum number of pieces that a pizza can be cut into by 7 knife cuts?**

A pizza is usually round shaped. So I was cutting a circle into pieces by seven straight lines. Minimum number is eight. But no maximum I am getting.

It is better to add complete answer with references. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This sounds like something belonging to Combinatorial Geometry.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169432/sword-pizza-and-watermelon would be of some help to you i believe...

Comment: This link is helpful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a known problem: it is appropriately called the [**Circle Cutting Problem**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyLines.html).

I suggest to you to read the linked page --- it is quite informative. However, the important part is that with $n$ cuts, you can divide a circle into at most $f(n)$ parts, where:

$$f(n) = \frac12\left(n^2 + n + 2\right)$$

In your case, $f(7) = \frac12(49+7+2) = \frac12(58) = 29$.

Comment: @Newb How do we prove the above formula?

Answer (score 7):

Let's apply [Euler's polyhedron formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic)$$1-V+E-F+1=0$$ to the plane graph formed by the $n$ chords (straight knife cuts), assumed to be pairwise intersecting with no three concurrent, and the rim of the pizza. The number we want is $$f(n)=F-1=E-V+1$$ since we don't want to count the outer face which has no pizza. The number of vertices is$$V=\binom n2+2n,$$i.e., $\binom n2$ points where two chords cross, and $2n$ points where chords meet the rim. The number of edges is$$E=n^2+2n,$$i.e., each of the $n$ chords is cut into $n$ segments, and the rim in cut into $2n$ arcs. Our final answer is $$f(n)=E-V+1=n^2+2n-\binom n2-2n+1=\frac{n^2+n+2}2=\binom{n+1}2+1$$and so, for $7$ cuts,$$f(7)=\binom82+1=29.$$

Comment: Neither do I. I think [Euler's polyhedron formula](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/eulers-formula.html) was mentioned in the solid geometry class I took in 12th grade.

Answer (score 5):

When you make a straight cut through a whole or already-sliced pizza, you divide each piece that you slice through into two pieces; that is, you create $p$ new pieces, where $p$ is the number of pieces you slice through.  Your cut starts in some piece, and then crosses into a new piece for each line it traverses; so $p=c+1$, where $c$ is the number of *cuts* you slice through.  And for the $n$-th cut, you can slice through at most all of the preceding $n-1$ cuts, so $p=c+1\le n$.

Putting this together, the maximum number of pieces after $n$ cuts is at most
$$
1+1+2+3+\ldots+n=1+n(n+1)/2,
$$
or $29$ pieces after $7$ cuts.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try to cut the pizza into as many pieces as possible.  Put $p_n$ as the number of pieces after $n$ cuts. Then $p_0 = 1$ and $p_1 = 2$.  Next $p_3 = 4$ if we cut across the first cut.  For a general $n$, we cut across all $n$ lines and get $p_n = n + p_{n-1}$.  Hence
$$p_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n p_k = 1 + {n(n+1)\over 2}. $$

Answer (score -1):

For 'n' number of cuts,

i) Mininum Number of pieces = (n+1)

ii) Maximum number of pieces = Sum of the values of n

Eg : For 3 cuts, 
Min pieces = 3+1 = 4
Max pieces = 1+2+3 = 6

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this answer?

Comment: Max pieces is 7 for 3 cuts